# Is there a way to use android's Play Core to install local apk?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-core

If the apk is in local storage, there's a way to use Play Core interface to install it? Without having to go to Play Store to download it?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the apk from local storage by clicking on it on your android device. If an "Open with" window appears, select "Package Installer". Then it should get installed.